# Eclipse on Ubuntu 17.04, can't run c code after building it: Launch failed. Binary not found

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-17.04

I am new to eclipse CDT on Ubuntu and I can not run my program successfully. I am able to build my code and binaries then occur on the left navigator. However, when I try to run my program, there is an error saying "Launch failed. Binary not found". I was just running the sample Hello-world program.

My OS is Ubuntu 17.04.

[image: The error message]

Comment: i think you must change your build command under run menu

Comment: There is no build command under run menu. I just clicked the build button. You mean changing the builder or binary parser? I tried to change it to PE Windows as a solution suggested, but it is not working.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt gcc
`

Comment: And i suggest to ask your question under [ask-UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not know this website before.\